# Service which getString in onStartCommand always return null

Tags: java, android

i want to run services in my runnable class.
This is my runnable class.

```
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(mContext,InitLocationsOnStartup.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("stations",json);
            mContext.startService(serviceIntent);
```

I need to get `"stations"` string in my `onStartCommand` function.But onStartCommand's `intent` always `null`.That's mean always return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT;` So How i get my string?

**InitLocationsOnStartup**

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (null == intent || null == intent.getAction ()) {
                String source = null == intent ? "intent" : "action";
                Log.e (TAG, source + " was null, flags=" + flags + " bits=" + Integer.toBinaryString (flags));
                return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = intent.getStringExtra("stations");

            stations = gson.fromJson(json,new TypeToken<List<StationViewModel>>(){}.getType());
                setProximityAlert(addLocation(locationList));
```

Comment: try after separate `if(null == intent || null == intent.getAction ())` conditions and check you log that in what you getting null `intent` or `intent.getAction ()`

Comment: Try calling setAction() on the intent before starting the service or remove the null check for the action.

Comment: I tried setAction() but i get "PlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!" error @UpendraShah

Comment: It sounds like that error is beyond the scope or the original question regarding the null action. It is probably best to start a new topic showing more code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Elletlar